# NX3031 Multifunction 1/10-Gigabit Server Adapter not detected in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, drivers

I installed Ubuntu server on an HP ML380 G6. Unfortunately, the embedded NIC wasn't detected.

Here is the output from **lshw -class network**:

```
  *-network:0 UNCLAIMED   
   description: Ethernet controller
   product: NX3031 Multifunction 1/10-Gigabit Server Adapter
   vendor: NetXen Incorporated
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:06:00.0
   version: 42
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: msix pm msi pciexpress cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:fae00000-faffffff memory:f8000000-f9ffffff
  *-network:1 UNCLAIMED
   description: Ethernet controller
   product: NX3031 Multifunction 1/10-Gigabit Server Adapter
   vendor: NetXen Incorporated
   physical id: 0.1
   bus info: pci@0000:06:00.1
   version: 42
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: msix pm msi pciexpress cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:f7e00000-f7ffffff memory:f4000000-f5ffffff
  *-network:2 UNCLAIMED
   description: Ethernet controller
   product: NX3031 Multifunction 1/10-Gigabit Server Adapter
   vendor: NetXen Incorporated
   physical id: 0.2
   bus info: pci@0000:06:00.2
   version: 42
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: msix pm msi pciexpress cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:f3e00000-f3ffffff memory:f0000000-f1ffffff
  *-network:3 UNCLAIMED
   description: Ethernet controller
   product: NX3031 Multifunction 1/10-Gigabit Server Adapter
   vendor: NetXen Incorporated
   physical id: 0.3
   bus info: pci@0000:06:00.3
   version: 42
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: msix pm msi pciexpress cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:efe00000-efffffff memory:ec000000-edffffff
```

I installed **hp-firmware-nic-netxen-5.6.3-1.1**

```
./nxflash.bin -i p2p1 -a nic_fw/phantom_romimage
nxflash error : No such device
nxflash error : No such device
```

**uname -a** returns

```
 4.10.0-28-generic #32~16.04.2-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jul 20 10:19:48 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**lspci -nnk | grep 0200**

```
 06:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: NetXen Incorporated NX3031 Multifunction 1/10-Gigabit Server Adapter [4040:0100] (rev 42)
 06:00.1 Ethernet controller [0200]: NetXen Incorporated NX3031 Multifunction 1/10-Gigabit Server Adapter [4040:0100] (rev 42)
 06:00.2 Ethernet controller [0200]: NetXen Incorporated NX3031 Multifunction 1/10-Gigabit Server Adapter [4040:0100] (rev 42)
 06:00.3 Ethernet controller [0200]: NetXen Incorporated NX3031 Multifunction 1/10-Gigabit Server Adapter [4040:0100] (rev 42)
```

I don't know what to do ...

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `lspci -nnk | grep 0200`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated the firmware of my network adapter, after that everything works fine.